# Add a new column in Pandas as Max of existing column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sas

I need to convert below SAS code to python pandas. I am not getting exact result with what i have tried.

Below SAS code to convert into pandas:

```
proc sql;
create table t1 as
 select 
  c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, flag, max(flag) as MAX_flag
from t1
 group by c1, c2, c3,  c5;
run;
```

I tried like this: Its working for this example but with large dataset i am getting mismatch.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['z','y','x','x','z','y','z','y','x','z',], 
               'B':[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0],
               'ID':[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,3,4]})
 df=df.sort_values(['A','B','ID'], ascending=[True,True,False])
 df.loc[:,'Max']=df.groupby(['A','B'])['ID'].cummax()
```

I want to convert above SAS to pandas. Please let me know if any one has done it.

Comment: expected output is how i can use max function to achieve above sas equivalent in pandas thats it... i mean just need to convert above SAS in pandas

Comment: The expected output is quite obvious John Galt, just read the question / SQL code...

Comment: If so, OP's working solution for sample example isn't correct. If he could give the expected output, that shall correct his/your understanding. Hope that helps.

Comment: actually i am able to do like this df=df.groupby(['A','B'])['ID'].max() .... but i need a new column called Max_flag that will have the max value. So number row will not get disturbed. Just need the same result of SAS code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use transform to get back the result in row-wise form.

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   A  B  ID
0  z  0   0
1  y  1   1
2  x  2   0
3  x  0   1
4  z  1   0
5  y  2   1
6  z  0   0
7  y  1   2
8  x  2   3
9  z  0   4

In [28]: df['max'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['ID'].transform(np.max)

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   A  B  ID  max
0  z  0   0    4
1  y  1   1    2
2  x  2   0    3
3  x  0   1    1
4  z  1   0    0
5  y  2   1    1
6  z  0   0    4
7  y  1   2    2
8  x  2   3    3
9  z  0   4    4
```

Comment: thanks it worked. .. what is the correct and best way to add a new column in pandas... df['max'] or df.loc[:,'Max'] ?

Comment: can u please update your answer w.r.t to my question